# Longest acyclic path in a directed unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

What algorithm can be used to find the longest path in an unweighted directed acyclic graph?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).  It is also referenced in [Longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), given that it is a DAG.

The following code from Wikipedia:

```
algorithm dag-longest-path is
    input: 
         Directed acyclic graph G
    output: 
         Length of the longest path

    length_to = array with |V(G)| elements of type int with default value 0

    for each vertex v in topOrder(G) do
        for each edge (v, w) in E(G) do
            if length_to[w] <= length_to[v] + weight(G,(v,w)) then
                length_to[w] = length_to[v] + weight(G, (v,w))

    return max(length_to[v] for v in V(G))
```

Comment: This returns just the length of the path. Can the code easily be modified to return the path?

Comment: Yes, the same way with most DP problems -- keep track of the previous and go back on it.

Comment: `topOrder(G)` is the list of vertices of G in [topological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Comment: the loop therefore starts from the 'sources' (no incoming edges) and ends with the 'sinks' (no outgoing edges)

Comment: a [paper with same algorithm](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/11-Graph/Docs/longest-path-in-dag.pdf) but easier to follow the rationale in case you need it.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the graph is acyclic, all you need to do is negate the edge weights and run any shortest-path algorithm.

**EDIT:** Obviously, you need a shortest-path algorithm that supports negative weights. Also, the algorithm from Wikipedia seems to have better time complexity, but I'll leave my answer here for reference.

Comment: and do we keep the negative weights as negative ? :p

Comment: @Hellnar: nope, if you have negative weights in the original graph, they should become positive. w' = -(w)

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has an algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Looks like they use weightings, but should work with weightings all set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved by critical path method:
1. find a topological ordering
2. find the critical path
see [Horowitz 1995], Fundamentals of Data Structures in C++, Computer Science Press, New York.

Greedy strategy(e.g. Dijkstra) will not work, no matter:1. use "max" instead of "min" 2. convert positive weights to negative 3. give a very large number M and use M-w as weight.