# Optimization of movement on board

Tags: algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory, mathematical-optimization

Suppose you have a n x n gaming board and you have a character that can move like a knight on a chess board except he can't move up or left. And each block he moves to has a value which can be accumulated to his points. The player is trying to maximize points and reach T

I came up with a solution but im wondering where it could fail and its run time.

My idea was to create a directed weighted graph (points as weights) to each possible destination and run Dijkstra's algorithm on the graph, however instead of shortest path, we 
try and find the longest path.

[image: Picture]

I am guessing the run-time would be O (some thing  + |E|+|V|log||V|)

Im not sure what something is.

Comment: It seems to me that the graph is acyclic, in that case there are fast algorithms: [ref1](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11295/finding-shortest-and-longest-paths-between-two-vertices-in-a-dag) [ref2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525316/longest-acyclic-path-in-a-directed-unweighted-graph), [ref3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths)

Comment: The algorithm doesn't work there can be cyclic cases

Comment: Hm I thought your restriction to down and right movement would make this acyclic.

Comment: I'm sorry what I meant to say was it moves like a Knight on chess board black lines on picture but its messing parts of the movement of the knight

Comment: Sure, got that, but I couldn't find a circle anyway. Maybe I am just missing an obvious case.

Comment: Yes you are right it can not come back to a point it has already been, but what would the runtime of graph construction be?

Comment: Assuming you index the nodes by their position on the field (x,y) then you can get each neighbour for a given node in constant time dynamically, so the runtime of the algorithms should not be affected.

Comment: Since there are only types of moves allowed, this seems to be some special case of Bresenham's algorithm (except for the allowed permutations of the X,Y steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dijkstra is not good for finding maximum path. In ordrer to find the maximum path you should multiply each edge weight by `-1` and it is well known that dijkstra does not operate correctly on graph with negative weight edges. Instead you will need to use [Bellman-Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). The complexity will then be `O(| V |  · | E |)` as stated in the wikipedia article.

Comment: Your answer works, but i think Dijkstra will also work because there will never be a negative edge either. 

I never thought of multiplying by -1 and finding shortest path, its clever.

Comment: @RandomGuy if you multiply all edges by `-1` **all** edges will be negative