# Python - find longest path

Tags: python

The function will take in a dictionary as input, and I want to find the length of a longest path in a dictionary. Basically, if in a dictionary, key2 matches value1, and key3 matches value2, and so forth, this counts as a path. For example:

```
{'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}
```

In the case above, the length should be three. How would I achieve this? Or more specifically how would I compare keys to values? (it could be anything, strings, numbers, etc., not only numbers)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you need to "compare keys to values" ?

Comment: I don't know how to check otherwise... I'm new to programming

Comment: Is it possible that you have a loop, e.g. `{'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d', 'd' : 'a'}`?

Comment: Yes! and the function should terminate and give out a warning. Otherwise the length will be infinite.

Answer (score 6):

I would treat the dictionary as a list of edges in a directed acyclic graph (DAG) and use the `networkx` module to find the longest path in the graph:

```
import networkx as nx

data = {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(data.items())
try:
  path = nx.dag_longest_path(G)
  print(path)
  # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

  print(len(path) - 1)
  # 3
except nx.exception.NetworkXUnfeasible: # There's a loop!
  print("The graph has a cycle")
```

Comment: This works precisely! Sorry I should've mentioned this in the original post, but is there any way of doing this without using modules?

Comment: There must be. But why? You would have to reimplement the functionality of `networkx`.

Comment: If you still decide to go for it, a long and winding path is ahead, and here's where to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880419/how-to-find-the-longest-simple-path-in-a-graph

Comment: @DYZ because the user could be coding in a work environment that doesn't have the networkx module.

Comment: @Yvonne I would go with this solution. Finding longest path is [NP complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) (similar to "traveling salesman" and you'd rather choose a well crafted solution and not a solution someone comes up in a stackoverflow answer. Otherwise you'll run into very slow run times.

Comment: Note: the version of `networkx` on github now supports weighted edges also :)

Comment: this is the most efficent way I've ever test, there's 1000+ records in my data dict, the speed is really impressive, thanks!

Comment: @AndyP: but that only works for *shortest path*, not the longest path? https://github.com/networkx/networkx

Comment: **Note** that this does not support a dictionary containing a list of values.

Answer (score 1):

If you're insisting on not importing anything you could do something like:

```
def find_longest_path(data):
    longest = 0
    for key in data.iterkeys():
        seen = set()
        length = -1
        while key:
            if key in seen:
                length = -1
                raise RuntimeError('Graph has loop')
            seen.add(key)
            key = data.get(key, False)
            length += 1
        if length > longest:
            longest = length

    return longest
```

Comment: `raise RuntimeError('Graph has loop')` makes `length=-1` and `break` unnecessary.

Comment: You're right. I added the `RuntimeError` after I re-read the question.