# Longest path in unweighted undirected graph - each node visited only once

Tags: algorithm, graph

how can I get **longest path** in unweighted undirected graph if each node can be visited only once? Thanks for help! // I am new to graphs.I've found out that **each edge can be visited only once**,not node.Node can be visited **more times**.Does it mean that my graph is **directed**? Thanks

Comment: How big is the graph?

Comment: Search google for `diameter of graph`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Longest acyclic path in a directed unweighted graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525316/longest-acyclic-path-in-a-directed-unweighted-graph)

Comment: @stil, does not seem so; that question is about a DAG, which makes a problem much easier.

Comment: I'm new to graphs.I've found out that each edge can be visited only once,so does it mean that it's directed? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously an NP-complete problem, as [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem can be reduced to this one. So you will most probably have no polynomial solution here. For non-polynomial you can just use brute force, or try to adapt numerous Hamiltonian path approaches.

Comment: You sure this is NP-complete? Can you elaborate a little how Hamiltonian path can be reduced to diameter of graph?

Comment: @vish4071 The diameter of a graph is the longest *shortest* path. OP asks for the longest path. Those problems are completely unrelated.

Comment: @vish4071, assume we need to solve Hamiltonian path on a graph. Let's instead solve the OP's problem: find the longest path which visits each vertex at most once. If this path visits _every_ vertex, it is Hamiltonian. Otherwise, it is obvious no Hamiltonian path exists, as if it existed, it would make a better solution for OP's problem.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele, you have wrong idea of diameter. It is defined as "longest distance between 2 nodes in a graph", which is obvs what OP is asking.

Comment: @vish4071 right, where "distance between 2 nodes" is defined as the shortest distance... see for instance [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html).

Comment: @Petr, but here we do not have to visit each vertex. Its just that, if we start with a vertex and do BFS, then, the last level will tell us the length of diameter (if this node is one of the end points of diameter of course). So, doing BFS from each node gives us the length in O((v+e)*v) as we are doing BFS `v` times. Some modification in this should give diameter itself.

Comment: @vish4071, consider a simple triangle graph -- three vertices, three edges. The answer to OP's question will be path of 2 edges, 3 vertices, while your algorithm will just find path of 1 edge, 2 vertices.